# Как объяснить функции что за переменная?

Tags: javascript

Как объяснить функции какое значение мы передали?

Объект передаем такого типа

```
obj = { "Апельсины": {"price": 4,"kolvo": 2},"Бананы": {"price": 2,"kolvo": 0} }
```

Но выведет результат и с ценой и количеством

```js
var items = {
  "Апельсины": {
    "price": 4,
    "kolvo": 2
  },
  "Бананы": {
    "price": 2,
    "kolvo": 0
  }
};

notification(items, (kolvo) => kolvo === 2)

function notification(items, condition) {
  for (const name in items) {
    let price = items[name].price
    let kolvo = items[name].kolvo
    if (condition(price)) {
      console.log(name + price)
    } else if (condition(kolvo)) {
      console.log(name + kolvo)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Уточните вопрос, что Вы хотите видеть в итоге выполнении функции?

Answer (score 1):

Никак. Надо завести две функции - одна проверяет условие для цены, а вторая - для количества.

Если хочется поизвращаться, то можно дополнительный параметр передать, либо и с именем поля, либо просто флаг. Но это ннеудобно и неправильно.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var items = {
  "Апельсины": {
    "price": 4,
    "kolvo": 2
  },
  "Бананы": {
    "price": 2,
    "kolvo": 0
  }
};

// check price
notification(items, item => item.price === 2);
// check quantity
notification(items, item => item.kolvo === 2);

function notification(items, condition) {
  for (const name in items) {
    if (condition(items[name])) {
      console.log(name, JSON.stringify(items[name]));
    }
  }
}
```

```js
var items = {
  "Апельсины": {
    "price": 4,
    "kolvo": 2
  },
  "Бананы": {
    "price": 2,
    "kolvo": 0
  }
};

notification(items, objCheck => {
  for(var prop in objCheck)
    return objCheck[prop] === 2;
});

function notification(items, condition) {
  for (const name in items) {
    var price = items[name].price;
    if (condition({price})) {
      console.log(name, JSON.stringify(items[name]));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Думаешь, ему нужны 2 вызова notification?

Comment: @Qwertiy может - да, может - нет. Смысл - перенести логику проверки в функцию-параметр.

Comment: @lgor спасибо за помощь, но Qwertiy прав. Пытаюсь реализовать с одним вызовом.

Comment: @NyanSoldier Закомментируйте один из вызовов - останется один.